# If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ then there exists a normal subgroup $K$ such that $G/K$ is isomorphic to $P/P \cap G'$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory, p-groups

In 'Finite Groups' by Gorenstein, it is stated that if $P$  is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ then there exists a normal subgroup $K$ such that $G/K$ is isomorphic to $P/P \cap G'$′. The proof is the following:

$P \cap G'$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G'$, as $G/G'$ is abelian and $G' \triangleleft G$. If $K$ denotes the inverse image of $O_{P'}(G/G')$ in $G$, $P \cap G' = P \cap K$, $K \triangleleft G$ and $G/K$ is an abelian $p$-group isomorphic to $P/P \cap G'$.

I understand the first line, and that $O_{P'}(G/G')$ represents the maximal normal $p'$-subgroup of $G/G'$ but don't quite understand what the inverse image is, or how this immediately yields $P \cap G' = P \cap K$, could anyone explain this in better terms?

Comment: Please state the theorem with an [edit].

Comment: The theorem was in the title, but I put it in the text body if thats what you were referring to :)

Comment: Thank you. Of course, yes; I'm sorry :)

Comment: The inverse image is, by definition,  the group $K$ with $G' \le K$ such that $K/G' = O_{p'}(G/G')$. Clearly $P \cap G' \le P \cap K$, and $|K:G'|$ is not divisible by $p$, so we get equality.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!